# How to Calculate average case after doing HTTP benchmark

Tags: performance, algorithm, math, benchmarking

If i do a benchmark, and for example i found the following:

1. With 1 concurrent user, The api give 150 req/s. (9000 req/minute)
2. With more than 300 concurrent user, The api start throwing exception.
3. An app is doing request 1 every 30 minute.

Is it correct if I say:

1. the best cases is that the api could handle (30 * 9000 = 270.000 user). That is under 30 minute, there would be 270.000 sequential request and each are coming from different user
2. The worst cases would be when there is 300 user posting request at the same time.

And if it's true, would there any way to calculate the average case ?
Is is the same as calculating worst case, average case complexity of an algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

One theoretical tool to answer these questions is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory. It says that you are very unlikely to get the level of performance that you are assuming, because the load applied to the system fluctuates, so that there are busy periods and quiet periods. If the system has nothing to do in quiet periods it is forced into idleness that you haven't accounted for. In busy periods, on the other hand, it will typically build up long queues of pending work, until the queues get so long that customers walk away, or the queues become longer than the system can support and it collapses, or both.

The graph at figure 1 page 3 of http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dsmyers/cs547/lecture_12_mm1_queue.pdf shows a graph of response time vs applied load for what is probably the most optimistic even vaguely realistic situation. You can see that response time gets very large as you approach maximum load.

By far the most sensible thing to do is to run tests which apply a realistic load to your application - this is important enough for people to build things like http://jmeter.apache.org/. If you want a rule of thumb I'd say don't plan to stress the system at more than 50% of theoretical capacity as you originally calculated.